# JQuery: how to update variable as browser resizes?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready ( function () {
        var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
        $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
        $('#footer').css('marginTop', - footerheight);
        $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
    });
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
        $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
        $('#footer').css('marginTop', - footerheight);
        $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
    });
</script>
```

Is this the proper/preferred way to set the variable "footerheight" to update as the browser resizes? The top half of the script obviously determines the variable when the document loads but I'm not sure if the bottom half is scripted properly to update that variable as the window expands/contracts.

Answer (score 5):

You could condense it a little by using a variable, like:

```
var f = (function () {
       var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
       $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
       $('#footer').css('marginTop', -footerheight);
       $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
   });

$(document).ready(f);
$(window).resize(f);
```

For resizing alone use [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
    $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
    $('#footer').css('marginTop', - footerheight);
    $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
        $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
        $('#footer').css('marginTop', - footerheight);
        $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
    }).resize();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var pageFoot = $('#footer');
        function updateFoot(){
            var footerheight=pageFoot.height();
            pageFoot.css('marginTop',-footerheight+'px'); // Doesn't have any sense to set the css height here like you do in your function.
            $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom',footerheight+'px');
        };
        $(window).on('resize', updateFoot);
        updateFoot();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).resize(function(){
            var heightBody = $(window).height();
            $(".content_cards").height(heightBody - 135);
        });$(window).resize();
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you explain the answer in more detail? Why does your script is better than others? That's part of the question.