# Why my function not able to access the variables defined outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to set the layout of my search-bar using jquery. I.e. trying to set margins and padding as the screen size changes by using resize function. But not sure why it only works when the variables are defined within the function. Defining the variables again within the resize function will make the code look ugly and I am sure there is a better way to do it. Where am I going wrong in defining my variables ?

```
      <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            var inputList = $("#keysrch").width(), 
                $windwid = $(window).width(),
                $srhwrap = $("#srh-wrap").width(),
                $ulwidth = $("#keysrch").width()+$("#dropdwnopt").width()+$("#srh").width(),
                $paddingL = Math.round($srhwrap-$ulwidth)/4,
                $windwid_left_margin = ($windwid-$srhwrap)/2;

                $("#srhbarinput").css({"width":inputList});
                $("#srhbar_unlist").css({"padding-left":$paddingL});
                $("#srh-wrap").css({"margin-left":$windwid_left_margin});  

               $(window).resize(function(){

                var inputListchange = $("#keysrch").width(), 
                   kysrhwidth = inputListchange; 

                $("#srhbarinput").css({"width":kysrhwidth});
                $("#srhbar_unlist").css({"padding-left":$paddingL});
                $("#srh-wrap").css({"margin-left":$windwid_left_margin});
                console.log("Padding:"+$windwid_left_margin);   
               });              
        });

      </script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the variables every time the window is resized? You're going to need to assign them within the function, so that they are reset every time the event is triggered.

Comment: That's how functions work, the term for it is 'scope'. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions

Answer (score 2):

I believe the reason the variables are not working in your case is this. You are for example defining a variable of $windwid outside your function. So once your resize function triggers it is not resetting $windwid to the new window width.

You probably need $windwid = $(window).width() outside to set up your initial page, but then once the resize occures you need to re-read $(window).width() into your resize function.

As it stands you are only reading the window width once and you are not updating it in the resize function. You can define your varible outside your function, but you need to refresh it in your resize function, after the resize.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I did some more research and found my answer here,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907863/jquery-how-to-update-variable-as-browser-resizes